# Why can't qemu network through the bridge created by nmcli?

Tags: linux, networking, qemu

I am trying to create a permanent bridge device via nmcli:

```bash
$ BRIDGE="virbr0"
$ NETWORK_SEGMENT="192.168.122"
$ MASK=24
$ nmcli connection add type bridge con-name $BRIDGE ifname $BRIDGE autoconnect yes
$ nmcli connection modify $BRIDGE ipv4.address "$NETWORK_SEGMENT.1/$MASK"
$ nmcli connection modify $BRIDGE bridge.stp on
$ nmcli connection up $BRIDGE
$ ip a
...
16: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7e:7c:cb:a2:00:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global noprefixroute virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

After that I use this bridge for qemu virtual machine:

```bash
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
...
    -netdev "bridge,br=$BRIDGE,id=kvm0" -device 'virtio-net,netdev=kvm0' \
...
```

I found that the qemu virtual machine cannot connect to the network.

My network configuration in the virtual machine, as well as the host's NAT configuration, are completely correct, because I found that the bridge I created using brctl and ip, qemu can connect to the Internet through it:

```bash
$ sudo brctl addbr $BRIDGE
$ sudo ip addr add "$NETWORK_SEGMENT.1/$MASK" dev $BRIDGE
$ sudo ip link set dev $BRIDGE up
$ sudo brctl stp $BRIDGE on
$ ip a
...
17: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7e:7c:cb:a2:00:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Is there any difference between these two ways of creating bridges, except that bridges created by `brctl` cannot exist forever?

How can I create a persistent bridge that can be used with qemu?

Comment: Have you checked the syslog to see if a reason is given?